# What is the Transcend TS256GSSD720 erase block size and write block size?

Tags: ssd

Does anyone know what is the Transcend SSD TS256GSSD720 erase block size and write block size?

Apparently, the Support team at Transcend doesn't know this, because I asked them 2 months back and I haven't got an answer.

Answer (score 3):

After 2 months, eventually, they got back to me.

2MB for erase block size, and 8192 bytes for write block size.